# Using Atmosphere to return JSONP serialized objects

Tags: java, jersey, comet, atmosphere

I would like to use Atmosphere in one of my projects and have some problems using it to return simple POJO-s serialized into JSONP. I do not understand the relation between the @Produces annotation and the necessary `com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONWithPadding` object that I used successfully before to serialize my POJO-s in a simple RESTful service.

Here is my suspending method:

```
@GET
  @Path("/notification")
  @Produces( { "application/x-javascript", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  @Suspend
  public JSONWithPadding getNextNotification(
    @QueryParam("callback") @DefaultValue("callback") String callback) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.setMessage("Message is " + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));
    n.setMessage("S-" + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));
    return new JSONWithPadding(n, callback);
  }
```

This returns the appropriate JSON string to me as expected. And here comes the problem. I have the broadcaster method that returns:

```
@Broadcast({XSSHtmlFilter.class, JsonpFilter.class})
  @GET
  @Path("/broadcast2")
  public Notification broadcast2() {
    Random random = new Random();
    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.setMessage("Message is " + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));
    n.setMessage("S-" + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));
    return n;
  }
```

This produces the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.ericsson.nss.entities.Notificaion, and Java type class com.ericsson.nss.entities.Notification, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not fund
```

It seems that the framework would like to serialize the Notification object but is unable to do so. The `JsonpFilter` seems idle. I'm not sure if this method should return Notification or a `JSONWithPadding` wrapping object. If I remove the filters from the @Broadcast annotation, then the suspending method emits a "com.ericsson.nss.entities.Notification@308be6" string. This is nicer then the exception, but still not a JSONP message. Unfortunately the latest rest-chat demo built from maven repo is not operating (404 on /chat as mentioned by others).

If my broadcast method returns a `JSONWithPadding` instance and filters are off, then the broadcast request gets a valid JSONP response but the suspended thread returns com.ericsson.nss.entities.Notification@7f84c9 again.

Can you tell me how to use filters and annotations correctly?

(I am using the latest 0.9 version of Atmosphere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only make it work by returning `String` instances from my methods and handle JSONP serialization manually using Jackson.